# Fun with synonyms - "perhaps/maybe/probably"

Tags: word-choice, nuances, synonyms

What are the differences when using the following words/phrases to mean "perhaps", "maybe" or "probably"?

- 多分
- 恐らく
- 蓋し {けだし}
- もしかして
- ひょっとして
- なかろう (negative -> probably not)
- だろう / でしょう / であろう
- かも知れない

Please add any other words/phrases that provide similar meanings.

*N.B I hope istrasci doesn't mind me using his favorite question title pattern here :P*

Comment: You have であろう and なかろう but not だろう? For shame. :p (Regarding なかろう, the most obvious thing that comes to mind is that it's a literary construction. Colloquial Japanese would probably use ないだろう or its variants.)

Comment: @Zhen I thought でしょう should have already covered だろう because they are only different in informal vs formal, but, fine! I've added it to the list ... do you also want でござろう added along? :P

Comment: であろう is a variant of だろう, just as である is a variant of だ. (The relationship is exactly parallel.)

Comment: @Zhen I see. Then I put であろう in the same line as だろう and でしょう.

Comment: Big time!  Actually, I started intentionally use the same title format because it will help interested users find similar posts.  So when they pull up or search for any one of these, they should see the others that might interest them as well.

Comment: Also, might want to add もしかしたら and もしかすると next to もしかして (just different forms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that they often mix together, and are thus rather hard to tell apart…

Should I give exclusive nuances, I'd go like this:

- 多分:  Maybe. I don't know.  多分行きます。 (very often, 多分行くかもしれません)
- 恐らく: has a negative nuance by the kanji.  恐らく雨が降る
- 蓋し {けだし}: (never heard, I won't conjecture)
- もしかして: By any chance, would it be possible that… もしかして、彼女だったの？
- ひょっとして: Small, unimportant thing that may help you: ひょっとしたら、誰も気づかない
- かも知れない: way to round the corners, not to affirm too much. 彼が好きかもしれない。

なかろう / だろう / でしょう / であろう deserve their own question if it hasn't been done yet, for it can mean many things.  Basically, it can be a conjecture in which you want people to know that you think like this (the cake you give to your friend: おいしいでしょう？ The description of a party on facebook that happens it the middle of a thursday afternoon: 誰も来ないだろう！)

Comment: I have never heard of 蓋し either, but my dictionary says that it means "probably" so I'm hoping to see how it's actually being used ..

Comment: Regarding であろう, let's limit it to the usage that is similar to "僕が好きであろう曲を教えてください" (i.e. not as a sentence ending thing) ..

Comment: @Lukman: It is not possible to use だろう as a modifier, as far as I know. Grammatically speaking it is not so different from using, say, 行こう as a modifier.

Comment: @Zhen Are you referring to the usage of であろう in 僕が好きであろう曲? I found plenty of results in Google searches for "好きであろう[noun]" so I don't think that this usage is really ungrammatical or even colloquial ..

Comment: @Lukman: Interesting. I guess I need to look at more kinds of texts...

Comment: @Zhen I thought that the usage as modifier requires だろう to be decomposed into であろう, but Google searches for "好きだろう[noun]" give plausible results so maybe だろう can be used directly as modifier, but not でしょう since it has to be in plain form, I think :)

Comment: かもしれない means "might", which is more improbable than probable, whereas the rest seem more probable than improbable.

Comment: @istrasci: Do you mean that if using かもしれない shows that you are not so confident about the thing you are saying. I'm not so sure ... 本当かも知れない <-- can you feel my not-so-confident-ness in here?

Comment: @Lukman - Yes..

Comment: @istraci: when I hear girls say "彼が好きかもしれない", they in fact state that they *definitely* like the guy.  かもしれない is in quite many cases almost as meaningless as "you know" in American English.  It's just a way to ensure you didn't formally said what you thought by faking not being sure.

Comment: @Axioplase makes an excellent point here, I think. The true degree of commitment can be very fluid depending on social context. That's probably true in any language.